# Python - List.extend not returning expected value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am trying to get a list all numbers divisible by three under 1000. I used this code:

```
y = []
for x in range(1000):
    if not x % 3:
        y.extend(str(x))
print y
```

However it simply returned a seemingly unordered list of integers under 10, repeated in no apparent order (If you would like to see this list just say, but it is very long and probably not useful). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is giving you the right numbers, it's just splitting them into individual characters.

Try [`list.append`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) instead:

```
y.append(str(x))
```

Your meaning could be more explicit. It would make more sense to use `x % 3 == 0` than `not x % 3`

This could also be summarised into a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
y = [str(3 * i) for i in range(1000 / 3 + 1)]
```

Or, better yet (in my opinion), use [map](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) and [range](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#range):

```
y = map(str, range(0, 1000, 3))
```

`map` applies the `str` function to every item in the list generated by `range`.

As pointed out in the comments, `range` creates a list of its own, the size of which depends on the length of the list. You can use [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange) instead, to create an [xrange object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#xrange-type) which can be used in the same way:

```
y = map(str, xrange(0, 1000, 3))
```

This avoids the creation of an intermediate list.

Your question is tagged `python2.7` but note that in Python 3, the behaviour of `range` changes, so that it does what `xrange` does.

Comment: Note that since `map` is going to build a list, it's better to avoid the additional list that's built by `range` and use `xrange` instead.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my answer. Please let me know if you think it could be improved further.

Answer (score 2):

`extend` extends a list using another list. So when you try to extend a list using a string, it adds the digits of the number to the list.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend(str(12))
>>> l
['1', '2']
```

The correct operator to use would be `append`, which appends a list to another list. But you should just do this instead:

```
y = [x for x in xrange(1000) if x%3 == 0] # use xrange in python2
```

Or just:

```
y = range(0, 1000, 3) # thanks to Sebastian for this
```

Comment: or `y = range(0, 1000, 3)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: true :).

Comment: for the logic error, `not x % 3` is the same as if the modulus is zero

Comment: @mm865: my bad, did not see the `not`.

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
y.append(str(x))
```

in place of

```
y.extend(str(x))
```

in case of extend, x considered to be list. For example, "123" considered as list with '1','2','3' as it's elements

Answer (score 0):

**Just another explanation and how to fix your snippet:**

This is what list.extend says:

```
>>> help(list.extend)
Help on method_descriptor:

extend(...)
    L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
>>>
```

In your case as string is iterable so it will iterable over your string and convert into a list of characters and extend to the original one.

So, we can fix your snippet using tuple or list instead of str:

**Using single element tuple:**

```
y = []
for x in range(1000):
    if not x % 3:
        y.extend((x,))
print y
```

**Using single element list:**

```
y = []
for x in range(1000):
    if not x % 3:
        y.extend([x])
print y
```